# Calling a C++ Function from C Program

Tags: c++, c, makefile, linker, legacy

I am working on adding a function written in C++ to a large program written in C.

I have tried to surround all of the codes included in the C program in extern "C" blocks, but when I compile with g++, I still get the errors coming from compiler trying to compile C as C++. I have added the extern "C" blocks to all the headers and .c files as follows:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
{
#endif

//C code here

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

The errors look like this:

> ./sortcodes/oci.c: In function ‘int GetSpecList(ClientData,
>   Tcl_Interp*, int, Tcl_Obj* const*)’: ./sortcodes/oci.c:188:25: error:
>   ‘init’ does not name a type
>            static init=TRUE;

These errors do not occur if I remove my C++ function call and just compile the C program with gcc.

If I remove the extern "C" blocks and compile using options

> gcc -std=c++0x -lstdc++ -std=c++11

I get errors like the one below, where C++ flags were obviously ignored

> ./Event_Reader.cpp:9:20: fatal error: iostream: No such file or directory
>    #include

Are there any options that I am missing or misinterpreting? Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Some some [MCVE] please, and explain *all* your compilation commands. So [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53516322/edit) your question to improve it

Comment: To build your C++ source you need to use `g++`. Continue to use `gcc` to build the C sources.

Comment: `gcc -std=c++0x -lstdc++ -std=c++11` How is gcc supposed to stick to two different C++ standards at a time?

Comment: seems like your error has nothing to do with the `extern "C"`, the type of `init` is missing, see `./sortcodes/oci.c:188:25: error: ‘init’ does not name a type static init=TRUE;`

Comment: You forgot to show us the code where the error is reported. Looking at pieces that do not trigger an error message won't help.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude `gcc` is totally fine, since gnu automatically determines the language by the file extensions `.c` , `.cpp` ...

Comment: Basile, unfortunately I cannot include such an example as both the C and the C++ codes are massive. In the example of compilation with g++, there are errors coming from every single .c file included in the program.

Comment: The example of an error I gave is triggered by this line: static init=TRUE;

Comment: @NikolaySosnin seems like an syntax error in that file and has nothing to do with external linkage. `static init=TRUE;` is just plain wrong, since the type is missing, change that to `static int init=TRUE;` or some other type

Comment: @Korni, I would agree, but the program compiles well if I remove the C++ bits and just compile it as normal C.

Comment: @NikolaySosnin You could provide a short working example by extracting only needed information from your code

Comment: @NikolaySosnin there is a flag in the compiler called `default-int`, if the type specifier is missing in the source code `int` is assumed. C++  does not support `default-int`

Comment: @Korni *Except* that it doesn't add the path for the C++ standard library header files. Which is one of the problems the OP have.

Comment: @Korni, I have also suspected that line and I did re-declare it as static bool init = TRUE; This has worked to remove that particular error, but it does also mean that the original program is not handled in the same way as if I didn't include the C++ function, which seems suspicious to me and I cannot re-write all the C++ changes to all the C codes.

Comment: @NikolaySosnin the most clean and consitent way is to fix `./sortcodes/oci.c`, using `default-int` is bad coding behaviour imo. You'll maybe face other issue with the `ìnt` to `bool` workaround.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude your're right I missed that ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, to compile the c++ code you have to use a c++ compiler like g++ or clang++. Then, you need to declare the desidered c++ function with `extern "C"` linkage. At this point you can call the function from the C code.
Refer to [How do I call a C++ function from C](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/mixing-c-and-cpp#call-cpp) for a concrete example.

Comment: Thats wrong, as I stated in the comments above: `gcc` is totally fine, since gnu automatically determines the language by the file extensions .c , .cpp

Comment: @Korni Sure, ```gcc``` and ```g++``` are *essentially* the same software, but if you use ```gcc``` you will need to explicitly link against the standard template library. It is easier to simply use ```g++``` or ```clang++```. My answer emphasizes that ```c++``` code has to be compiled by ```c++``` compilers...

Comment: I have tried compiling with g++. But I have added external "C" to all the C codes. Should it be in the .cpp?

Comment: @NikolaySosnin In the c++ source you have to *declare* ```extern C``` only the c++ functions you want to use in the C code. Then in the C code you have to provide a declaration (without ```extern C```). Please have a look at the link.

Comment: @francesco The link has helped a lot, thanks! Moving the extern "C" to .cpp and declaring it at the top of the C code that used it has solved the compilation problems.